# How to use flowplayer to stream files from a remote server and don't use up traffic to http server?

Tags: streaming, flowplayer, traffic, litespeed

I've got a bit of a problem. I'm using flowplayer and a litespeed server to stream videos. The problem is that I'm using two servers, one of them is a http litespeed server that has my website/scripts and so on, and the other is used only for storage of video files and mysql database.

Some time ago a problem started occuring - the website got slow. After some investigating I found out that there's a lot of traffic between the two servers. The video hosting server doesn't send files directly to flowyplayer and to the client, instead it sends them to the http server and it then forwards the data to readers. I was wondering why is it like that?

Comment: Can you provide some configuration details of your Flowplayer?